# Angular 4 | How to wrap extra data in view more

Tags: angular

How can i wrap the extra data of my API. like for example, i have an API data which has 10 values and i want only 5 items of them to be shown and the rest will be put on (view more) with the corresponding number like. view more (5 items)

so far this code below display all the list of my data.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let apidata of data">
    <div class="box" *ngIf="apidata.Zone == 2">
      <div class="box-assignmentnumber-holder">
        <span id="AssignmentNumber">{{apidata.Assignment}}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="newAssignment" >
        <span>{{ apidata.Operator == null ? 'New' : apidata.Operator }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be cleaner to do this logic in your typescript class instead of the template. For example, you can do a similar loop in javascript and store the two different arrays that way, which you can then easily access in your template. Essentially you would end up with two ngFor loops in your template, but getting the count of the 'view more' list would be fairly straight-forward this way. Something like:

```
import { forEach } from '@angular/router/src/utils/collection';

let visible_list = [];
let view_more_list = [];

data.forEach(element => {
    if (element.Zone === 2) {
        visible_list.push(element);
    } else {
        view_more_list.push(element);
    }
});
```

Comment: nice and clean, so this means is im just pushing my data depending on what zone it belongs? like append in javascript?

Comment: can you make working plunkr or stackblitz for demo purposes?

Comment: Something like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/siKA10KtS9uA1UPNuKQd?p=preview

Comment: thanks for this man, but this is not what im looking for. i just want to display all data but it will slice only the 5 of it and the rest will be put on view more items.. something like that :)

Answer (score 2):

Please follow below POC and implement same logic in your code.

```
<button (click)="viewMoreClick()">View More...</button>
<div *ngFor="let item of items;let i = index;">
 <span *ngIf="(i < 6) || viewMoreValues">
  {{item}}
</span>
</div>
```

in your ts file :

```
 viewMoreValues = false;

 viewMoreClick() {
   this.viewMoreValues = true;
  }
```